# Binormal vector not plotting as expected

Tags: plotting, vector, differential-geometry

I cannot see why the binormal vector is not plotting orthogonal to **T** and **N**. Surely I am overlooking something. Do you see what it might be?

```
x[t_] = Cos[t];
y[t_] = Sin[t];
z[t_] = t;
r[t_] = {x[t], y[t], z[t]};
UnitTangent[t_] := Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]], t \[Element] Reals];
UnitNormal[t_] := Simplify[UnitTangent'[t]/Norm[UnitTangent'[t]], t \[Element] Reals];
UnitBinormal[t_] := Simplify[Cross[UnitTangent[t], UnitNormal[t]], t \[Element] Reals];
Manipulate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {0, 20}}, 
      BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 400],
    Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, Arrowheads[.013], 
      Arrow[{r[T], r[T] + UnitTangent[T]}]}, Axes -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 20}}],
    Graphics3D[{Thick, Green, Arrowheads[.013], 
      Arrow[{r[T], r[T] + UnitNormal[T]}]}, Axes -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 20}}],
    Graphics3D[{Thick, Black, Arrowheads[.013], 
      Arrow[{r[T], r[T] + UnitBinormal[T]}]}, Axes -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 20}}]],
 {T, .01, 20}]
```

Comment: It's probably because you don't have `BoxRatios -> Automatic`.  Rescaling with different factors along the axes does not preserve angles.  I'd recommend using something like `z[t] = t / 10`.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I thought that by setting them all to 1 I would avoid the very problem that it created. If you want to add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you don't have `BoxRatios -> Automatic`. Rescaling with `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}`, which gives equal-length axes in the output, does not preserve angles, unless the plot ranges on each axis are equal in length. I'd recommend using something like the following together with `BoxRatios -> Automatic`:

```
z[t] = t / 10
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]